# Django REST Framework Serialize model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Simple question:

I have next models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    surname = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)

clas Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, ...)
    title = models.CharField(...)
```

I wish to create an Album serializer that:

- Shows Artist information on GET
- Can link Artist using pk on POST

I can make the POST using pk using the following serializer, but I don't know how to GET artist information in the same serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you get your album object you should be able to do: `album.artist` and get your artist object

Answer (score 1):

You can override your `AlbumSerializer`'s [`to_representation` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior):

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = super().to_representation(obj)
        data['artist'] = ArtistSerializer(obj.artist).data
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is related to this [API Reference](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#api-reference) and to [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

It depends how you configure your `__str__` method inside `Artist` class.

**models.py**

```py
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    surname = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{name} {surname} - {age} years old".format(
            name=self.name, surname=self.surname, age=self.age)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['artist, ...']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but if you want to link two serializers you have to do the following:

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = '__all__'


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        exclude = '__all__'
```

However, if you just want to respond to a GET request, you should have the request object in the GET method, which essentially should contain the Album id and then you can link the two models together:

```
Album.objects.filter(pk=request['album_id']).first().artist
```

and get the artist associated with the particular album.